# How to only keep BMP in the utf-8 text file?

Tags: text-processing, unicode, character-encoding

This is the content of a text file, and I want to only keep BMP.

```
这是无效的字符  
这是正常的字符  哈
```

In the [How to remove non UTF-8 characters from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999651/how-to-remove-non-utf-8-characters-from-text-file)
, I find there is a solution, but it doesn't work here.

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c test.txt
```

[image]

The utf-8 of  is **F0A19B82** (located in `CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B`), utf-8 of 哈 is **E59388**（located in `CJK Unified Ideographs`).

If I want to delete all characters(the size greater than 3 Bytes) like  in text file , how to do it?

Comment: What makes these characters "non-UTF-8"?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Because the size of  is four Bytes, it should belongs to `utf8mb4` not standard utf-8.

Comment: Then you're asking a completely different question. You want to only keep characters in the BMP.

Comment: And "standard UTF-8" includes up to 7-byte characters (although none beyond 4 bytes currently exist).

Comment: OK, I edit my question, thank you! And I am a fresh man when facing  Ubuntu and character-encoding

Comment: Use of the term `utf8mb4` indicates that what you really have is a mysql problem. What mysql calls `utf8mb4` is what the rest of the world calls UTF-8. What mysql calls `utf8` is a restricted subset of UTF-8 that has no standard name. This is why it is inaccurate to refer to your goal as "deleting non-utf8". It's more like "mangling standard UTF-8 to squeeze it into a stupid encoding that only mysql uses".

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley welcome for you to edit if you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it through a charset that doesn't support the Supplementary Multilingual Plane, such as UCS-2.

```
$ iconv -f utf-8 -t ucs-2 -c input.txt | iconv -f ucs-2 -t utf-8
这是无效的字符  
这是正常的字符  哈
```

Answer (score 2):

Without resorting to tricks, perl is able to do exactly what you ask for:

```
$ perl -Mopen=locale -ne 's/[^\x{1}-\x{FFFF}]//g; print' infile
这是无效的字符
这是正常的字符  哈
```

Please take a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442466/265604) for additional solutions.

Comment: what’s `-Mopen=locale` mean? I haven't search anything result in Google.

Comment: And I find the output of `perl -Mopen=locale -ane 's/[^\x{1}-\x{FFFF}]//g; print' infile` is correct. The `-a` option seems didn't do anything.

Comment: @partida [Let me google that for you:](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Mopen%3Dlocale)

Comment: @partida And: [What is the best way to ensure Perl uses the locale encoding (as in LANG=en_US.UTF-8) for STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR, without affecting file IO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399629/how-can-i-get-perl-to-respect-the-locale-encoding-for-stdin-stdout-stderr-witho)