# Why is sed failing to follow collate order?

Tags: sed, locale, character-encoding

On this command:

```
$ echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" |
>      sed 's/[a-z]//g'
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

It seems correct, doesn't it?
However, the locale in effect is `en_US.utf8`. The [collating order for such locale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442225/match-language-range-in-shell-sed-or-awk) is (using bash):

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%x\\0' {65..90} {97..122})" | sort -z; echo
aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ
```

Or, if your `sort` can not use -z:

```
$ printf '%s' $(printf '%s\n' {a..z} {A..Z} | sort); echo
aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ
```

If that is correct, the range `[b-y]` should match all the characters above except `aAYzZ`.
But it doesn't.

---

Grep does the same on `[a-z]`. It match all lower case characters (even accented):

```
$ printf '%s' $(printf '%s' {a..z} {A..Z} éáíèüÉÁÍÈÜ | grep -o '[a-z]'); echo
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzéáíèü
```

And with `[a-Z]` it match all characters (that range should be invalid):

```
$ printf '%s' $(printf '%s' {a..z} {A..Z} éáíèüÉÁÍÈÜ | grep -o '[a-Z]'); echo
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZéáíèüÉÁÍÈÜ
```

Comment: Which sed, GNU or BSD?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Using GNU sed at the moment, but: Shouldn't both follow LC_COLLATE? Could you report about both/any?

Comment: My understanding is that `[a-z]` explicitly only includes lowercase characters, regardless of where the uppercase letters fall in the lexical order.

Comment: [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) says: `Within a bracket expression, a range expression consists of two characters separated by a hyphen. It matches any single character that sorts between the two characters, inclusive. In the default C locale, the sorting sequence is the native character order; for example, ‘[a-d]’ is equivalent to ‘[abcd]’.`

Comment: @JeffSchaller It only specify the C-locale. In other locales it is not specified in that page, but I believe I have seen that the collate order in effect should be used. I have not been able to find the confirmation yet.

Comment: Ther'es also [POSIX - sed - BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03): `In the POSIX locale, a range expression represents the set of collating elements that fall between two elements in the collation sequence, inclusive. In other locales, a range expression has unspecified behavior: strictly conforming applications shall not rely on whether the range expression is valid, or on the set of collating elements matched. A range expression shall be expressed as the starting point and the ending point separated by a <hyphen-minus> ( '-' ).`

Comment: @JeffSchaller On the same page, under the heading **[a-z] is case insensitive** you may read: *POSIX mandates that [a-z] uses the current locale’s collation order … that means using strcoll(3) instead of strcmp(3).* It confirms that for GNU sed the collating order should be used. Thanks!.

Comment: @JeffSchaller So, in POSIX, *In other locales, a range expression has unspecified behavior…*. Does that mean that [a-z] shall not be used in any other locale, or just that POSIX allow the implementations to match the collating order?

Comment: I don’t have an Answer, thus my breadcrumb comments; sorry!

Comment: However, [posix page for sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) states that LC_COLLATE should *Determine the locale for the behavior of ranges, equivalence classes, and multi-character collating elements within regular expressions.*

Comment: IMHO, having `[a-z]` meaning `[a-zA-Y]` would be quite non-intuitive... and sure to raise a flamestorm.

Comment: @vonbrand Then it is just a matter of changing **documentation** to exactly define what is meant. If is decided that it must mean lowercase letters from a to z in ASCII order, then please **do** say that, not "collate order".

Comment: @isaac, "just change the documentation" to state it does something completely off the trodden path. Are you serious?

Comment: @isaac, ASCII text.

Comment: @isaac, Unix tools grew up in ASCII environment, anything deviating too much from that will give endless grief. Use `[a-z]` to mean anything but (possibly accented) lowercase letters is sure to cause a stink.

Comment: @vonbrand Isn't exactly that what I said in *it must mean lowercase letters from a to z in ASCII order*? What else are you reading?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is, that you would like to grep or sed a range of characters.

Using **sed:**

```
$ printf '%s' $(printf '%s\n' {a..z} {A..Z} | sort) | sed 's/b[^|]*y//g'
aAYzZ
```

Using **grep:**

```
$ printf '%s' $(printf '%s' {a..z} {A..Z} éáíèüÉÁÍÈÜ | grep -o "a[^|]*z"); echo
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```